# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM. Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.skm</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApps</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent> <!-- Problem -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This line `<parent>` is causing problem.

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.skm:MyApps:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.2.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.2.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

I have seen these links but unable to resolve it.

[Maven: Non-resolvable parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612309/maven-non-resolvable-parent-pom)
[Maven: Non-resolvable parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364693/project-build-error-non-resolvable-parent-pom)

Comment: Try to change `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` by `<relativePath /> `, it is not finding the pom from that route

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven Problems: Project build error: Non-resolved parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366826/maven-problems-project-build-error-non-resolved-parent-pom)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are pointing to a Parent pom that does not exist in your `local repository`. You should remove value for `<relativePath>` tag so that maven could fetch the pom file from maven `central repository`.

Change your parent tag as shown below.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Comment: By default it was like as you said but it didn't solve problem. Still facing same issue.

Comment: @faizan I didn't realise it was a internal nexus repository that you are using... You may want to delete the .m2 folder in your current directory to force the artifacts to re-download...

Comment: Should I create a new project?

Comment: I have been successfully able to compile my project. Thanks