# Non-resolvable parent POM for Maven (Spring Starter Project)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am new to spring and I'm trying to create a Spring Starter Project. However there is an error in my pom.xml. Here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>chatbot_api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>chatbot_api</name>
<description/>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The line `<parent>` here is the one causing the problem.

[image: complete error message]

I have seen these links but it did not resolved my problem.

- [Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM. Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364469/project-build-error-non-resolvable-parent-pom-failure-to-transfer-org-springfr)
- [Maven: Non-resolvable parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612309/maven-non-resolvable-parent-pom)

Comment: `connect timed out` suggests that either you weren't connected to the Internet or you need to configure a proxy. If you don't need a proxy, the problem will fix itself in an hour, or you can run `mvn -U dependency:resolve` to force a refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create settings.xml for proxy in m2 dirctory as below :

> Under Linux/Unix, place it under ~/.m2/settings.xml.  Under Windows
>   place it under c:\documents and settings\youruser.m2\settings.xml or
>   c:\users\youruser.m2\settings.xml.

Please refer [apache article](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html) for more details on settings.xml