# Java intellisense not working when imported projects not available

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm reviewing an isolated Java project in VSCode. By that I mean that I have the project itself, but not any of the projects that it depends on. From what I can tell, the result is that Intellisense has been turned off for the project, which makes navigating around the code a pain.

For example, you can see below that VSCode can't find the definition of a method, even though it's just 3 lines down. On the side, you can see the errors it's encountered trying to load various artifacts.

[image]

Is there a way to turn Intellisense back on, at least for the objects that are defined within the project itself? I have the MS Java extension pack installed.

To clarify, these are internal projects that it depends on and I don't have on my machine.

Comment: Are your dependencies configured through the Java Project Manager and is the setting `"java.project.referencedLibraries"` set?

Comment: @carson can you expand on that? This is the first time I've dealt with Java in VSCode

Comment: Also, to clarify, these are internal projects that it depends on and I don't have on my machine.

Comment: Can you share the project in github if convenient for me to reproduce your question?

Comment: @MollyWang it's tricky because it's one of those sprawling enterprise IT projects

Comment: All those unresolvable errors in your image are making me think there's a problem with your project building on your machine. Try taking your IDE out of the picture and just drop to the shell/command prompt and build it with just maven, i.e. mvn clean compile. If you can't build the project stand-alone, then you need to fix your mvn settings so you can properly resolve all the artifacts (presumably from one of your sprawling enterprise repositories where they are published). Once you get to that point, I think you'll have much better success at Intellisense working.

Comment: @atmas that's the problem, I don't have access to those other repos. I've only got this project, which the devs cloned for me, essentially. I'm reviewing the code, ie I'm not a member of the dev team so I don't have access to any of their other stuff

Comment: I see. Any chance you can get maven installed and the appropriate dev group's settings.xml files from them? If this is an enterprise environment, it seems fair for them to give you the actual tools to build the project they're asking you to review.

Comment: @atmas that's possible, but will take time. I was just looking for a quick way to get Intellisense working for the objects defined in this package. Just being able to jump to a definition would be great, rather than having to do a search

Comment: I hear you. Sorry I couldn't be of immediate help. If you're willing to, you can try a different ide (i.e. maybe Eclipse) and see if it works better with your project out of the box. If you do try eclipse, just use File -> Import -> Existing Maven Projects to load your project up.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed there's a feature that might help you get around this. Check out "Lightweight Mode" here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project

Maybe this will get away from having access to mvn full resources and just get the quick-n-dirty navigation as the docs seem to indicate!

> Lightweight Mode
>
> VS Code for Java supports two modes, lightweight and standard. With
> lightweight mode, **only source files and JDK are resolved by the
> language server; with standard mode, imported dependencies are
> resolved and the project is built by the language server.**

> ...**works best when you need a super quick-to-start and lightweight
> environment to work with your source files, for example, reading
> source code, navigating among source code and JDK**, viewing outline and
> Javadoc, and detecting and fixing syntax errors. Also, code completion
> is supported within the scope of source files and JDK... Lightweight mode **doesn't resolve imported dependencies nor build the project**.

Comment: Thanks for finding that! Unfortunately it doesn't look like it supports go to definition, which is the main thing I was hoping for. Still, at least it's got rid of the build error notifications.

Comment: That's too bad. It looked too promising as the final answer. I started to fool around with my VsCode to add the extensions and try to do it myself, but I'm already used to Eclipse and setup that way and then it wanted me to start downloading a new JDK.. It was just a bridge too far. I will leave this answer up though since it looks like it helped a little and may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your project throwed `project build error: Non resolved parent pom for com....`.

When errors are resolved, the intellisense should work as normal.

Please have a look at this question. Try and see if error goes away.

> [Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364469/project-build-error-non-resolvable-parent-pom-failure-to-transfer-org-springfr)